# Basis for infinite-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, logic

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $D$, and $U \subseteq V$ a subset.
Prove that the following are equivalent:

1. For each $v \in V - \{0\}$ there exist unique $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $u_1,...,u_n \in U$ pairwise disjoint and $k_1,...,k_n \in K  - \{0\}$ such that $v = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{k_i u_i}$
2. $U$ is a maximal set of vectors linearly indipendent.

The fact that the second implies the first is obvious: my problem is regarding the opposite implication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sum a_iu_i=0$ with $a_i\neq0$ then the representations in $1.$ would not be unique because $$v=\sum k_iu_i=\sum(k_i+a_i)u_i$$

Therefore $U$ are linearly independent.

If you add $v\neq0$ to the collection $u$, then $0=\sum k_iu_i-v$ is a non-trivial linear combination of $U\cup\{v\}$ that is equal to zero. Therefore you can't enlarge $U$ without making it linearly dependent.

Comment: The problem is that in our hypothesis  0  isn’t write in unique way like a linear combination of element of U

Comment: @Sara That doesn't come from assuming 1, that comes from assuming $U$ is **not** linearly independent. From that assumption and the assumption of 1 we get the contradiction that some non-zero $v$ can be written in non-unique way as a combination of $U$. From the contradiction it follows that $U$ **are** linearly independent.

Comment: Dear @Pp., I am sorry, but I simply misunderstood your answer! I have just re-read it, and sounds complete and clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that $U$ is linearly independent, and that it is *maximal* (that is, it has no linearly independent proper superset).

For the first one, assume that $U$ is *not* linearly independent -- that is, there is a nontrivial linear relation. With a bit of shifting around you should be able to find a $v$ such that the combination of $n$ and $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ is *not* unique (as assumed).

For the second, assume that $W$ is a proper superset of $U$. Choose $v\in W\setminus U$, and apply the hypothesis about $U$ to this $v$. This will give you a nontrivial linear relation in $W$, so $W$ is not linearly independent.